# Need to make multiple Async calls before executing next step JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, flux

I have an array that can hold an unknown amount of indexes in it. Each index is used to send data with an `ajax` call. I am looping through with a `for loop` gathering the data from the successful call and pushing it into an empty array. At the end of the unknown amount of calls I then need to use that newly gathered array in my view. `newDataArray` is executed at the bottom before the loops are done and therefor it is still empty. How do I finish all the calls then do what is at the bottom?

If it helps, I am doing this in React with the Flux pattern. But the same issue may be done not in React. Here is a mock sample of what I am trying to do:

JS

```
case 'execute-calls':

    //This is the new array to push to
    var newDataArray = [];
    //Url to call
    var url = 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp';

    for(let i = 0; i < payload.data.length; i++){

        //given array of data that needs to be sent with call
        let symb = { symbol: payload.data[i]};
        $.ajax({
          data: symb,
          url: url,
          dataType: "jsonp",
        })
          .done(function(data){
            let updatedData = {
              //...data that is stored from response
            };

            newDataArray.push(updatedData);
          })
          .fail(function(error){
            //console.log(error);
          });

      }

    //This will be updating the state object which is above the switch cases
    //However this is ran before the end of the loops so newDataArray is empty
    var updateTicker = {
        updatedTicker: true,
        updatedTickerSymbols: newDataArray
    };
    assign(stockData,updateTicker);
    getStockData.emitChange();

    break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) actually returns a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), and use it to create an array of deferreds. e.g.

```
var symbols = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var deferreds = symbols.map(function (symbol) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp',
    data: { symbol: symbol },
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
});
```

You can resolve multiple deferreds at once with [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). There is a complication however, $.when() expects a list of parameters rather than array. We can solve this by using `Function#apply`.

To add to the complication, the callback function is also called with a list of arguments. Since we don't know how many arguments there are, we'll use the `arguments` pseudo-array. And since arguments isn't an *actual* array, we'll loop through it by using `Function#call` on `Array#prototype`.

```
$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function (response) {
    console.log(response[0].Message);
  });
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

[**UPDATED** to include fail() call]

If you're using ES6 this is much more elegant:

```
$.when(...deferreds).done((...responses) => {
  responses.forEach((response) => {
    console.log(response[0].Message);
  });
});
```

Comment: This way seemed most intuitive. Thanks for the answer. How do you see if an error was given from the response? will it be stored in one of the indexes? `$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function (response) {` where console logging response there would show an error?

Comment: Good point. There's also a fail callback. This will be invoked when the first error is encountered. I've updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you are dealing with ajax calls and have to do some operations at the end of all async calls then better choice would be to use `Callback` functions.

Modifying your code to use the call back,

```
 function AsyncLoopHandler(index) {
    if (index > payload.data.length) {
        // all the indexes have finished ajax calls do your next step here

        var updateTicker = {
            updatedTicker: true,
            updatedTickerSymbols: newDataArray
        };
        assign(stockData, updateTicker);
        getStockData.emitChange();
    }
    else {
        //given array of data that needs to be sent with call
        let symb = { symbol: payload.data[index] };
        $.ajax({
            data: symb,
            url: url,
            dataType: "jsonp",
        })
          .done(function (data) {
              let updatedData = {
                  //...data that is stored from response
              };

              newDataArray.push(updatedData);
              AsyncLoopHandler(index++); // call the function again with new index
          })
          .fail(function (error) {
              //console.log(error);
          });
    }  
}
```

Now for starting this recursive function just start it by passing the index 0.

```
  AsyncLoopHandler(0);
```

So all the ajax calls will be executed one after the other as if its an synchronous requests, And the `if` check will see if all the indexes are complete and then run your logic. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

suggest use promise, logic would like

```js
var urls= [x,x,x,x];
var results = [];
var qs = $.map(urls,function(url){
  return function(){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    $.ajax({
      success:function(){
        results.push(url)
        deferred.reslove();
      },error:function(){
        deferred.reslove();        
      }
    })
    return deferred;
  }
})
Q.all(qs).then(function(){
   console.log(results )
});
```

or use yield and co in new standard

https://github.com/kriskowal/q